# Folder shows Missing in Tortoise SVN Commit - How to disassociate this and move that missing item

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have added a new folder to one of my local working copies.  I have yet to initially check it in though.

I want to take it out and put it on my desktop, then branch and then put it back in and associate with the branched local version.

I noticed though, as I try to commit, that the folder is associated with that local copy because it's showing it as non-versioned in the Tortoise commit dialog.

How do I simply move it and disassociate it as though I had never placed it in my local working copy to begin with?  I'm not sure how to do that without screwing things up.

If I cut and paste it from my location to my desktop then click commit on the root of my local working copy, it says it's missing.  I want to get rid of that missing dependency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not associated. "Non-versioned" means not under version control. You should be able to safely remove it from the folder without harming the working copy.

Comment: If you do not want to see it as "Non-versioned", try svn ignore. There is a Menu Item in Tortoise for that.

Comment: weird, the only option I see is Delete and Ignore, not just delete

Comment: If I cut and paste it from my location to my desktop then click commit on the root of my local working copy, it says it's missing.  I want to get rid of that missing dependency

Comment: If it complains it's missing, then it *must* have been already added. Are you 100% sure it's not added yet? There is no "revert" in the Tortoise Context menu that pops up`? What kind of icon do the files have?

Comment: You're providing us with conflicting information here.

If you take the folder out of the directory and the working copy's status tells you that it's missing, that means the directory was added to the repository (even if not yet committed). Files that are not being tracked don't show up as missing. If this is the case, put it back where it was, and then perform a revert operation using that directory as the target.

If the file really isn't part of the repository, you will be able to take it out of the working copy and the WC would never be the wiser.

Comment: Maybe that's because I don't understand how Tortoise or SVN works.  That's why I posted.  I just left out that information because I was not aware that missing means it's being tracked.  I did not check in that folder so how is it tracked?

Comment: if I try to revert, it shows one .cs and a checkbox next to it.  I'm afraid if I revert, that it will override my local changes.

Comment: Ah crap! sorry, my fault.  I accidentally commited 2 classes in that folder by accident.  No wonder.  So if I revert them will they override my local copies?

Comment: You should definitely make backup copies first, but if your only commit action was to add the files, a revert *should* just un-add them. Be careful though.

Comment: Ok, I had to do a revert from this revision...which unfortnately writes over and replaces your local copy of that file.  Luckily I backed it up anyway and the class really only had one line change so after I did that, I just made a change back to where it should be and committed and in the commit dialog did a plane "revert" on that file to disassociate.

Comment: SVN can be a bitch in such details sometimes, I know. I once had to spend half a day (of my own time of course) fixing directories that I had screwed up by copy+pasting them within a working copy. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you ran the "Add" command on it, just run the "Revert" command on it and it will be un-added. Otherwise, just go ahead and move it.

Comment: yea, I didn't add yet...it's not versioned yet.

Comment: Just to be clear, `add` ing a file is not the same as versioning it. When you `add` it, you're *scheduling* it to be versioned on the next `commit`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a check box in the commit window at the bottom labeled "Show unversioned files" Uncheck this option and the non-versioned will not appear in your commit window.  As others said, the files were never associated